# Android move to left widget and fade in

Tags: android

in my layout i want to move some widget to left with fade in effect, after search on google and try to coding i cant, i can only find zoom in with fade in effect,

```
icon_back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    icon_back.setAlpha(0.f);
    icon_back.setScaleX(0.f);
    icon_back.setScaleY(0.f);
    icon_back.animate()
            .alpha(1.f)
            .scaleX(1.f).scaleY(1.f)
            .setDuration(350)
            .start();
```

how can i programically do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `translationX()` method in your animation:

```
icon_back.setX(200);
icon_back.animate().translationX(0);
```